# Joomla 3.2 Post Upgrade Errors (No Configuration File)

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I recently upgraded our site to Joomla 3.2. Post upgrade I was unable to access multiple areas of the backend and was receiving 404 errors. My decision was to take the site offline while I sorted it out. I could not take the site off line from the admin area, so I then changed `public $offline = '0';`  to `public $offline = '1';` in configuration.php. In order to save the file, I needed to change the permissions from 444 to 644. Immediately following this, i received the following error when visiting the site in the browser.

> No configuration file found and no installation code available.
>   Exiting...

I'm not sure how this would be a server issue as all of my other 3.2 sites are running smoothly. However returning configuration.php to its original state did not resolve the issue.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Your initial problem feels like it might have something to do with your htaccess file. Regarding configuration.php can you check it again and make sure that the code is still there?

Comment: Yes the htaccess file is still intact

Comment: is it `.htaccess` or `htaccess.txt` ?

Comment: also understand the this error only occurred after modifying the configuration.php and changing the perms in order to save it via ftp

Comment: Take a backup of your current htaccess and configurations.php files and try uploading 2 new fresh files from from a fresh Joomla installation. Once done, change the configuration.php settings so they match your site, such as the database settings.

Comment: i uploaded a fresh .htaccess file and a fresh configuration.php...FAIL

Comment: I now just attempted to reload configuration.php in my editor from ftp and its magically blank. grrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: disk usage limit reached in cpanel. this may be whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the server runs out of disk space. Try clearing folders tmp and cache...